# Disabled Mode, Microsoft Access 2016

Tags: ms-access

When trying to append data in Access 2016 and running a query, the following error is given and nothing happens: 'The action or event has been blocked by Disabled Mode.'

[Screen capture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0fIg.png)

Comment: Take a look to: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Stop-disabled-mode-from-blocking-a-query-0171e2dd-f9b0-4ffa-a542-2278ce1babb1

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a common issue, but most fixes that seem plausible, are all for MS Access 2007 or 2013. Try this fix - I believe it's from 2007 but it seems to be the only other alternative one I've found:

- [how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-in-access-action-or-event](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_other/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-in-access-action-or-event/cff9f885-2e7c-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5?msgId=0eea8099-347c-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5)